# Monitor connectivity in a Sesam instance

Tags: sesam

We need to monitor connectivity of some systems to help figure out when and where outages occur, to help debug network and VPN issues.

What would a good approach to this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Sesams rest API and query sesam itself, when checking the network status it will attempt to create a network socket to the system and give back the status.

System config:

```
{
  "_id": "system-monitor",
  "type": "system:rest",
  "authentication": "jwt",
  "jwt_token": "$SECRET(jwt_token)",
  "operations": {
    "get": {
      "headers": {
        "Content-type": "application/xml"
      },
      "method": "GET",
      "payload-type": "json",
      "url": "systems/{{ _id }}/status"
    }
  },
  "rate_limiting_retries": 1000,
  "url_pattern": "https://datahub-83ac2aaa.sesam.cloud/api/%s",
  "verify_ssl": true
}
```

Pipe config:

```
{
  "_id": "system-monitor-list",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "github-url"
    }, {
      "_id": "zoho-rest"
    }]
  },
  "transform": [{
    "type": "rest",
    "system": "system-monitor",
    "operation": "get"
  }, {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "_id", "_S._id"],
        ["add", "ts",
          ["now"]
        ],
        ["copy", "*"]
      ]
    }
  }],
  "pump": {
    "cron_expression": "*/15 * * * ?"
  },
  "compaction": {
    "keep_versions": 100
  }
}
```